# Reading Web-Based XML file and parsing it in Python

Tags: python, google-app-engine, xml-parsing

I am very new to Python and GAE but I am attempting to download an XML file from the eventful.com api (in XML), parsing it and I will then storing this information within a database on Google Cloud SQL.

My code so far is as follows which I have managed to write after looking at various online tutorials however I keep receiving many errors and the code will not work for me at all. If anyone has any pointers on where I am going wrong please let me know, Karen.

My Attempt to call the eventful xml file and parse it:

```
import webapp2
from google.appengine.ext.webapp import template
import os
import datetime
from google.appengine.ext import db
from google.appengine.api import urlfetch
import urllib #import python library which does http requests
from xml.dom import parseString #imports xml parser called minidom

class XMLParser(webapp2.RequestHandler):
    def get(self):
        base_url = fetch('http://api.eventful.com/rest/events/search?app_key=zGtDX6cwQ=dublin&?q=music')
        #downloads data from xml file
        response = urllib.urlopen(base_url)
        #converts data to string:
        data = response.read()
        #closes file
        response.close()
        #parses xml downloaded
        dom = parseString(data)
        #retrieves the first xml tag that the parser finds with name tag
        xmlTag = dom.getElementsByTagName('title')[0].toxml()
        #strip off the tag to just reveal event name
        xmlData = xmlTag.replace('<title>', '').replace('</title>', '')
        #print out the xml tag and data in this format:
        print xmlTag
        #just print the data
        print xmlData
```

I receive the following errors when I try to run this code however in Google App Engine user the GAE launcher -

```
2013-04-15 16:52:05 Running command: "['C:\\Python27\\python.exe', 'C:\\Program Files     (x86)\\Google\\google_appengine\\dev_appserver.py', '--skip_sdk_update_check=yes', '--port=8080', '--admin_port=8002', u'C:\\Users\\Karen\\Desktop\\Development\\own_tada']"
INFO     2013-04-15 16:52:17,944 devappserver2.py:498] Skipping SDK update check.
WARNING  2013-04-15 16:52:18,005 api_server.py:328] Could not initialize images API;     you are likely missing the Python "PIL" module.
INFO     2013-04-15 16:52:18,065 api_server.py:152] Starting API server at:      http://localhost:54619
INFO     2013-04-15 16:52:18,085 dispatcher.py:150] Starting server "default" running     at: http://localhost:8080
INFO     2013-04-15 16:52:18,095 admin_server.py:117] Starting admin server at: http://localhost:8002
ERROR    2013-04-15 15:52:35,767 wsgi.py:219] 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_appengine\google\appengine\runtime\wsgi.py", line 196, in Handle
    handler = _config_handle.add_wsgi_middleware(self._LoadHandler())
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_appengine\google\appengine\runtime\wsgi.py", line 255, in _LoadHandler
    handler = __import__(path[0])
  File "C:\Users\Karen\Desktop\Development\own_tada\own.py", line 8, in <module>
    from xml.dom import parseString #imports xml parser called minidom
ImportError: cannot import name parseString
INFO     2013-04-15 16:52:35,822 server.py:561] default: "GET / HTTP/1.1" 500 -
ERROR    2013-04-15 15:52:37,586 wsgi.py:219] 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_appengine\google\appengine\runtime\wsgi.py", line 196, in Handle
    handler = _config_handle.add_wsgi_middleware(self._LoadHandler())
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_appengine\google\appengine\runtime\wsgi.py", line 255, in _LoadHandler
    handler = __import__(path[0])
  File "C:\Users\Karen\Desktop\Development\own_tada\own.py", line 8, in <module>
    from xml.dom import parseString #imports xml parser called minidom
 ImportError: cannot import name parseString
INFO     2013-04-15 16:52:37,617 server.py:561] default: "GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1" 500 -
```

One such tutorial I used for the above code comes from the following URL: http://www.travisglines.com/web-coding/python-xml-parser-tutorial

EDIT:

Thanks to the help provided by Josh below I now am not receiving any errors when I launch my code with my code, however I only see a blank screen and want it to print out the parsed information (or its progress this far). I know this may seem like a very stupid question but I really am a beginner so I'm sorry! Fixed code (minus errors) is :

```
import webapp2
from google.appengine.ext.webapp import template
import os
import datetime
from google.appengine.ext import db
from google.appengine.api import urlfetch
import urllib #import python library which does http requests
import xml.dom.minidom as mdom #imports xml parser called minidom

class XMLParser(webapp2.RequestHandler):
    def get(self):
    base_url = 'http://api.eventful.com/rest/events/search?app_key=zGtDX6cwQjCRdkf6&l=dublin&?q=music'
    #downloads data from xml file
    response = urllib.urlopen(base_url)
    #converts data to string:
    data = response.read()
    #closes file
    response.close()
    #parses xml downloaded
    dom = mdom.parseString(data)
    #retrieves the first xml tag that the parser finds with name tag
    xmlTag = dom.getElementsByTagName('title')[0].toxml()
    #strip off the tag to just reveal event name
    xmlData = xmlTag.replace('<title>', '').replace('</title>', '')
    #print out the xml tag and data in this format:
    print xmlTag
    #just print the data
    print xmlData

app = webapp2.WSGIApplication([('/', XMLParser), 
                          ],
                          debug=True)
```

Any guidelines on what to do next would be greatly appreciated or anything on what you can spot is wrong with my python code, Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should fix your imports

```
import xml.dom.minidom as mdom
```

and parse the raw with:

```
dom = mdom.parseString(data)
```

As far as the data manipulation you are going to want to look into the childnodes and data elements returned from parseString.

Such as:

```
for element in dom.getElementsByTagName('title')[0].childnodes:
    print element.data
```

To see the structure once its been parsed.

Comment: Thank you @Josh this seems to have fixed the errors which I seemed to be having with my code but now I'm having the problem of viewing something when I run it in GAE (all I see is a blank screen). Sorry if this seems like a very stupid question - I must reiterate the fact that I am a total beginner! I would just like to see how it has parsed the xml file. I'll update my code in above main question! (that is now minus the errors)

Comment: Hi @Josh I have realized that the reason I was seeing a blank screen was that I had to check the error console for my returned results (Sorry about the dumb question again). I now am having new errors for the encoding of such text returned by the xml (which contains a star element). I've opened a new stackoverflow question to fix this but I have chosen your answer as the solution to the question I had asked here! Thank you. New Question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16026594/unicode-encoding-errors-python-parsing-xml-cant-encode-a-character-star?noredirect=1#comment22863206_16026594

Answer (score 2):

Appengine supports [lxml](http://lxml.de/parsing.html) it is very simple to [include](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/python25/diff27#Supported_Third-Party_Libraries) it and parse your document with it.

In your app.yaml file

```
libraries:
    - name: lxml
    - version: latest
```

and then `import lxml` and follow the [parsing](http://lxml.de/parsing.html) instructions