# Unable to Access Child Node in Parsing XML with Python Language

Tags: python, xml, python-2.7

I am very new to the python scripting language and am recently working on a parser which parses a web-based xml file.

I am able to retrieve all but one of the elements using minidom in python with no issues however I have one node which I am having trouble with. The last node that I require from the XML file is 'url' within the 'image' tag and this can be found within the following xml file example:

```
<events>
    <event id="abcde01">
        <title> Name of event </title>
        <url> The URL of the Event <- the url tag I do not need </url>
        <image> 
            <url> THE URL I DO NEED </url>
        </image>
    </event>
```

Below I have copied brief sections of my code which I feel may be of relevance. I really appreciate any help with this to retrieve this last image url node. I will also include what I have tried and the error I recieved when I ran this code in GAE. The python version I am using is Python 2.7 and I should probably also point out that I am saving them within an array (for later input to a database).

```
class XMLParser(webapp2.RequestHandler):
def get(self):
        base_url = 'http://api.eventful.com/rest/events/search?location=Dublin&date=Today'
        #downloads data from xml file:
        response = urllib.urlopen(base_url)
        #converts data to string
        data = response.read()
        unicode_data = data.decode('utf-8')
        data = unicode_data.encode('ascii','ignore')
        #closes file
        response.close()
        #parses xml downloaded
        dom = mdom.parseString(data)        
        node = dom.documentElement  #needed for declaration of variable
        #print out all event names (titles) found in the eventful xml
        event_main = dom.getElementsByTagName('event')

        #URLs list parsing - MY ATTEMPT - 
        urls_list = []
        for im in event_main:
            image_url = image.getElementsByTagName("image")[0].childNodes[0]
            urls_list.append(image_url)
```

The error I receive is the following any help is much appreciated, Karen

```
image_url = im.getElementsByTagName("image")[0].childNodes[0]
IndexError: list index out of range
```

Comment: Do not decode and re-encode the data! Leave decoding to the XML parser. Any reason you cannot use the [ElementTree API](http://docs.python.org/2/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html) instead of the minidom?

Comment: That URL returns an error response for me; I get an `Authentication Error` message. Perhaps you do too?

Comment: Hi @MartijnPieters, I have left out the api key for this example just as I thought it would keep it more simple. I can insert the api key if you feel this would be more useful however I am not having issues with this, it is more so accessing the elements of image tag. I have had to decode and reencode the xml data after it was parsed due to an encoding issue with a black star found within the xml data. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16026594/unicode-encoding-errors-python-parsing-xml-cant-encode-a-character-star/16073981?noredirect=1#16073981

Comment: That doesn't look like an issue with the *XML input* at all! There you are *encoding* Unicode data, the error does not lie with your XML. The problem there most likely is with the `print` stament and whatever is your `stdout` at that time. Without a traceback that is impossible to diagnose any further though.

Comment: No need for the API key, just covering all the bases.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, do *not* reencode the content. There is no need to do so, XML parsers are perfectly capable of handling encoded content.

Next, I'd use the [ElementTree API](http://docs.python.org/2/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html) for a task like this:

```
from xml.etree import ElementTree as ET

response = urllib.urlopen(base_url)
tree = ET.parse(response)

urls_list = []
for event in tree.findall('.//event[image]'):
    # find the text content of the first <image><url> tag combination:
    image_url = event.find('.//image/url')
    if image_url is not None:
        urls_list.append(image_url.text)
```

This only consideres `event` elements that have a direct `image` child element.